# Selenium IDE vs Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium

Which one of the following should be preferred for automating web project

1. Selenium IDE
2. Selenium WebDriver

I want to automate web application and this question is creating hell of confusion in my mind

Comment: This is not a good question for SO. For one thing, the choice to make is based on the specifics of the project for which the choice should be made. However, even if this question were edited to add a substantial chunk of specifics, I'm not sure it would not avoid being opinion-based.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

selenium IDE should be considered if you have very little knowledge on coding and your requirement is to create play-back recorded scripts. also if u have small size web app and with low maintenance scope then go for selenium IDE.
If your web app is dynamic with lots of test cases and you are sure that maintenance will be required then go for selenium web driver. For that you will require good programming language knowledge.
Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Selenium IDE is only for Firefox browser where as Selenium WebDriver will work in all kinds of browsers.